# Can we write a stored procedure in a computed column in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, calculated-columns

I have a situation where I want to place a stored procedure in a computed column. But it didn't work out so I used function instead. Can computed column have stored procedure??

Comment: elaborate more on your question.

Answer (score 3):

No, they can't.

Stored procedures are not "inline", they don't return scalar values and can have all manner of side effects.